# Google App maker dropdown null item name

Tags: google-app-maker

In App maker for drop downs there is a option to set nullItemName, default one is No selection. In my scenario we are taking values from models which has empty values I want to show empty values as blanks but if we change the nullItemName property.

It is changing for the default app maker one and the empty values from the models. Image is attached for the reference.

Here you can see two same values one is app maker default No selection and the other in from the datasource empty item.

[image: Dropdown image]

Comment: Null is null... what is sense to show exact same option multiple times? You can just filter out nulls from the drop down options...

Comment: we are not showing multiple options, one is the default value and the other option is from the model. we are providing options from model. Pleas let us know how can we rename the options

Answer (score 1):

Dropdown widget has two properties: options and names. By specifying both of them you'll explicitly tell App Maker to display specific name for each option:

```js
// options
[1, null, 3, 4]

// names
['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four']
```

**Editor**

[image: Options/names editor]

**Runtime**

[image: Options/names runtime]

For sure you can use binding for these properties.

Comment: We are taking options from models through bindings, In this case how can we change the names

Comment: `@datasource.MyDatasource.items` for `options` and `@datasource.MyDatasource.items..Names` for `names`.

Comment: If we set @datasource.MyDatasource.items for options, OK button is not enabled to save the expression

Comment: Replace `MyDatasource` with datasource name you actually need. And it looks like I made a typo in previous comment, it should be `@datasources....`

Comment: Did you try to select it with UI instead of typing?

Comment: I selected from UI only

Comment: That is strange, it works for me. Feel free to report bug to AM team.

Comment: Okay I will report